# Why database connection getting fail after few time

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am using MYSQL database and basic JDBC connection pool for connect to the database. application is deployed in tomcat server. After few operations, database connection getting null.

could any one please let me know the reason for that ?

Comment: "because". do you expect us to be able to just guess at what the problem is,s ince you've basically given us absolutely nothing useful in the way of code or descriptions? basically: "it's broken, fix it!"

Comment: And also please post the actual error

Comment: The reason could be a signal C90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen for a few different reasons:

1. Not calling `close()` on your `Connection` resources when you're done with them. This can cause your connection pool to be exhausted after all the `Connection`s are handed out and not closed.
2. Calling `close()` on your `Connection` resources more than once. Closing a `Connection` returns it to the pool so another thread can grab it. If you call `close()` a second time, you've now closed it for the other thread.
3. Your code is actually setting your `Connection` instance to `null` somewhere.
4. You're leaving a `Connection` resource open and idle for too long and it's timing out on you. If your code has some long running operation between queries, consider closing the `Connection` and getting a new one between queries.
5. The database server closed your connection for some reason and your connection pool doesn't know about it. To mitigate this, you can configure your connection pool to test on borrow. This would basically issue a test query on the connection to make sure it's alive before handing it over to you app. Note: there is some overhead there.